# COUNT is more than what I have

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL statement

```
SELECT COUNT(appl.applicantID) 
FROM course_Batch pD 
INNER JOIN applicant appl ON pD.programmeID = appl.programmeID
GROUP BY pD.programmeID
```

So, in my `applicant` table, I've 2 applicants tied to a `record` in my `course_Batch`.

However, when I use that SQL statement I pasted above, I get 4. Because in my `course_Batch` table, I've multiple records under 1 `programme ID`.

`ProgrammeDetail` table with sample data:

```
-------------------------------------------
|  programmeID  |   programmeRequirement  |
-------------------------------------------
|     P01       |          20             |
|     P01       |          20             |
-------------------------------------------
```

`Applicant` table with sample data:

```
-----------------------------------
|   applicantID  |   programmeID  |
-----------------------------------
|    A001        |      P01       |
|    A002        |      P01       |
-----------------------------------
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  programmeID  |   programmeRequirement  |   applicantCount  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|   P01         |          20             |         2         |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `Count(Distinct applicantID)`

Comment: projectCode ??? Anyway, first figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: ProgrammeDetail isn't in your query and there's not sample data for course_Batch. Can you edit your question?

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server databases? If not, remove the inappropriate tag.

Comment: What would the result look like if your firste table also contained a third record with programmeID  P01 and programmeRequirement 30?

Answer (score 1):

Use `INNER JOIN` . It will give your expected result

```
 SELECT
    programmedetail.programmeID,
    programmedetail.programmeRequirement,
    COUNT(
        DISTINCT (applicant.applicantID)
    ) AS applicantCount
FROM
    programmedetail
INNER JOIN applicant ON programmedetail.programmeID = applicant.programmeID
GROUP BY
    programmedetail.programmeID,
    programmedetail.programmeRequirement;
```

By clicking on the below link you can see your expected result in live which you want.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/EBBS22477)